# Date and Time in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

In my app I want the time/date to display as Month/Year (e.g. 7/10). The problem is sometimes I get class Date and sometimes class Time so I wind up with the following code in the application controller ...

```
class Date
  def as_month_and_year
    self.strftime("%m").to_i.to_s + self.strftime("/%y")
  end
end

class Time
  def as_month_and_year
    self.strftime("%m").to_i.to_s + self.strftime("/%y")
  end
end
```

what's the best way to DRY this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the more elegant solution:

```
module DateTimeExtensions
  def as_months_and_year
    self.strftime('%m/%y').sub(/^0/,'')
  end
  [Time, Date, DateTime].each{ |o| o.send :include, self }
end
```

Comment: It's elegant, but extending three built-in Ruby classes for what is a simple view concern is IMHO overkill in this situation.

Comment: it's the railsway: http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/

Comment: I'm fully aware that the ActiveSupport module provides all sorts of useful extensions to Ruby's classes, but that's because Rails is a *framework*. It also provides the view helper mechanism for exactly this type of problem.

Comment: What is the down vote for? I really would appreciate a comment. It's funny to get an accepted answer down voted, and I'm really interested why?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a view helper method that accepts a Date or Time instance and formats appropriately. No need to re-open the Date and Time classes. This sort of thing is exactly what the view helper modules are for.

```
def as_month_and_year(date)
  date.strftime("%m").to_i.to_s + self.strftime("/%y") 
end
```

Then in your views you can just use:

```
<%= as_month_and_year(@object.created_at)
```

Comment: `date.strftime("%m/%y")` != `self.strftime("%m").to_i.to_s + self.strftime("/%y")` it doesn't remove the leading zero

Comment: I did that, but when I went to in-place-editing I created another helper...

  def editable(this_model, this_element, args={})
    classes = "editable".join(args[:class]," ")
    s = args[:format] ? this_model.send(this_element).send(args[:format]) : this_model.send(this_element)
    "<span class='#{classes}' id='seeker-#{this_model.id}-#{this_element}'>#{s}</span> "
  end

used like this in haml...
= editable(experience, "date", :format=>:as_month_and_year, :class=>"arial10")

and while I could figure out how to do this with a class method, I couldn't figure out how to use the helper method.

Comment: Please post that as a separate question, because it's really not related to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
module DateTimeExtensions
  def as_month_and_year
    self.strftime("%m").to_i.to_s + self.strftime("/%y")
  end
end

class Date; include DateTimeExtensions; end
class Time; include DateTimeExtensions; end
class DateTime; include DateTimeExtensions; end
```

Comment: And a little shorter with:  `self.month + self.strftime("/%y")`